# Como extraer tablas de un excel para cruzar con otra base de excel en python

Tags: python, excel, tablas

Buen dia, tengo el siguiente inconveniente, el cual quiero resolver con python ya que lo estoy empezando a aplicar.

Tengo un archivo de excel en la hoja = "Hoja1" que contiene varias tablas de excel y otro que tiene datos descargados de un sistema ERP, el cual necesito enviarle esa la info de las tablas al archivo de excel que me dejan del sistema ERP.

Ejemplo.

Archivo donde se encuentran las tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo base que me deja el ERP

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema radica en que se como extraer las tablas para hacer un merge con el del sistema ERP si estan en hojas distintas, pero no si estan en una sola hoja, yo se cual es el nombre de las tablas.

dbo_razon_social_pagadora

dbo_datos_proveedor

podria resolverlo con un buscarv en excel, pero mi objetivo es hacerlo con python para luego aplicarle otros cambios que ya tengo armados.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar directamente pandas para leer cada tabla especificando el archivo, la hoja y el rango de columnas y filas. Obviamente, tienes que saber en que rango en excel estan ubicadas tus tablas.

Supon que tenemos un excel que se lama `tablas.xlsx` que contiene la Hoja 1 con dos tablas. Usando el comando:

```
#!pip install xlrd
import pandas as pd
tabla1 = pd.read_excel('tablas.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Hoja 1', skiprows = 2,  nrows= 2, usecols = 'B:C')
tabla2 = pd.read_excel('tablas.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Hoja 1', skiprows = 3,  nrows= 3, usecols = 'F:H')
```

Lo que hacemos es guardar en un dataframe los contenidos de la hoja `hoja1` donde hacemos un `skiprows` de tantas filas tengamos en blanco arriba y especificamos ek numero de filas de datos y las columnas a usar.

Para dos tablas seria algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He puesto las columnas desalineadas para ver que lo puedes hacer independientemente de su localizacion, siempre y cuando sepas donde esta ubicada la tabla.